# Mocking returns Mock Object instead of return value

Tags: python, python-3.x, mocking

I mocked the following function **os.getenv**, but instead of getting the return_value I specified, the Mock Object itself is returned. What am I doing wrong here?

```
    @staticmethod
def setup_api_key():
    load_dotenv()  # loading apikey and secret into PATH Variables
    api = os.getenv('APIKEY')
    secret = os.getenv('SECRET')
    return api, secret
```

The test looks like this:

```
    def test_setup_api_key(self):
    with patch('os.getenv') as mocked_getenv:
        mocked_getenv = Mock()
        mocked_getenv.return_value = '2222'
        result = Configuration.setup_api_key()
        self.assertEqual(('2222', '3333'), result)
```

Comment: If `setup_api_key` is defined in module `foo`, you need to mock `foo.os.getenv`, not `os.getenv`. `foo.os` and `os` are two different names for the same module, and patching is just a process of redefining names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `patch` in the context-manager fashion, the object you get (`mocked_getenv`) is already a `Mock` object so you don't have to recreate it:

```
def test_setup_api_key(self):
    with patch('os.getenv') as mocked_getenv:
        mocked_getenv.return_value = '2222'
        result = Configuration.setup_api_key()
        self.assertEqual(('2222', '3333'), result)
```

You can make this code a bit simpler by providing the return value directly when creating the context manager:

```
def test_setup_api_key(self):
    with patch('os.getenv', return_value='2222') as mocked_getenv:
        result = Configuration.setup_api_key()
        self.assertEqual(('2222', '3333'), result)
```